# Render only a part of the sphere inside the cube in OpenGL using python?

Tags: python, opengl, render, physics, pyopengl

I want to render only the parts where it is inside the cube to something similar that is shown in 2 figure

my current Code to render a sphere is here

```
def Sphere(ball):
    glPushMatrix()
    sphere = gluNewQuadric()
    glTranslatef(ball.pos.x,ball.pos.y,ball.pos.z) #Move to the place
    glColor3fv((1,0,0)) #Put color
    gluSphere(sphere, ball.radius, 16, 8) #Draw sphere
    glPopMatrix()
```

[image: Current]

[image: Required]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define clip panes with [`glClipPlane`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glClipPlane.xml). e.g.:

```py
glEnable(GL_CLIP_PLANE0)
glClipPlane(GL_CLIP_PLANE0, [1, 0, 0, distance])

glEnable(GL_CLIP_PLANE1)
glClipPlane(GL_CLIP_PLANE1, [0, 1, 0, distance])

# [...]
```

See also [OpenGL overlapping ugly rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56056083/opengl-overlapping-ugly-rendering/56064820#56064820)